# Geometry of deformation of Axial members connected to a rotating rigid element

Tags: statics

On axial members connected to a rotating rigid element,

[image]

we have the following relationship
$$\frac{-\delta_1}{a}=\frac{\delta_2}{b},$$

which is based on the concept of similar triangles.
In the relationship, what is $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ refers to the lengths of the rotating rigid member corresponding to the deformed member that is being attached.